# Why am I not getting a response on frontend after axios request to backend (Node.js + React)

Tags: reactjs, axios

This is my index.js backend side

```
//Body-Parser to JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
}))
//Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secretcode',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(cookieParser('secretcode'))

app.get('/' , (req , res) => {
    res.send("HELLO WORLD")
    console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL + process.env.MONGO_MIDDLE + process.env.MONGO_ENDPOINT)
})

//Route for sending the email
app.use(contactRoutes)

//Routes for authentication
app.use(authenticationRoutes)
```

The authentication Routes file

```
//Register User
router.post('/registerUser' , authentication.registerUser)

module.exports = router
```

The registerUser.js is like this

```
const Customer = require('../models/Customer.js')

const registerUser =  (req , res) => {
    //Checks to see if that email is already being used
    Customer.findOne({Email: req.body.data.Email} , async (err , doc) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if(doc) res.json("Already Exists");
        //If user does not exist then create one
        if(!doc) {
            const newCustomer = new Customer({
                Email: req.body.data.Email,
                Full_Name: req.body.data.Full_Name,
                Phone_Number: req.body.data.Phone_Number,
                Password: req.body.data.Password
            })
            await newCustomer.save()
            res.json({message: "Created"})
        }
        
    })
}

module.exports = {
    registerUser
}
```

My axios request on the frontend is like this

```
const signupHandler = async () => {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/registerUser' , {
            data: {
                Email: email,
                Full_Name: fullName,
                Password: password,
                Phone_Number: phoneNumber
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.message)
        })
    }
```

Basically the console.log(res.message) part is not console logging anything. In the registerUser controller the code successfully saves the data to the database with no errors and moreover after operation I am not getting any error in the console. So i am just wondering why it is not showing on the frontend. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page was refreshing on submit and that was what was causing the json message to not show up. I fixed it by simply preventing page from refreshing on submit.

```
const signupHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/registerUser", {
    data: {
      Email: email,
      Full_Name: fullName,
      Password: password,
      Phone_Number: phoneNumber,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  console.log(data.message);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios returns data in the data property:

```
const signupHandler = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/registerUser", {
    data: {
      Email: email,
      Full_Name: fullName,
      Password: password,
      Phone_Number: phoneNumber,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  console.log(data.message);
};
```

Comment: Still did not work, I even tried commenting everything and doing a res.json({message: "hello"}) and tried to console.log that but it did not show up

Comment: Still not showing anything on console

Comment: I noticed something, when I submit the form the page is refreshing, could that be the issue ?

Comment: Yes, it could. Please check if API does actually return something in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Yea solved it below, you can upvote it since that is the solution